# xquery to order with header values in the way

Tags: sql-server, xquery

Can you partially order xml data types using an xquery when the logical columns aren't consistent (such as when there are headers in the first row(s))?

**Edit** Had a bad example, mislead answers away from original question.  How could I order the `typ` column values, leaving the th headers at top? Or vice versa, ordering by the integer column `rts` instead?

Say I have this XML stored in an mssql XML field (`select thexml from xmldata` returns one row containing the following):

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>typ</th>
    <th>rts</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>26</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DCC</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DBB</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>XBQ</td>
    <td>152</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AHI</td>
    <td>349</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now say I want to sort this by the HTML column `typ`.  I'm looking for the following result:

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>typ</th>
    <th>rts</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>26</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AHI</td>
    <td>349</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DBB</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DCC</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>XBQ</td>
    <td>152</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any XQuery experts who can break this down for me?

Comment: The best would be to have the header in a `<thead> ` and the content in a `<tbody>` element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort on a particular column, reconstruct the table and then sort on non header rows:

```
SELECT thexml.query('
  element table {
    /table/@*,
    /table/tr[th], (: copy header :)
    for $r in /table/tr[not(th)] (: exclude header :)
    order by $r/td[1] (: $r/td[2] to sort on rts col :)
    return $r
  }')
FROM xmldata
```

Comment: I'll keep it in mind, but technically, I'm looking for the more generic option of sorting by whatever values appear in that column, or a different column.  I could easily ask this question about sorting on `rts` instead.

Comment: @cocogorilla the `rts` column is inherently sortable because it's an integer. The best you can do for the `typ` column is sort alphabetically, which would actually meet the requirements of your example; however, add more data and it will fail for day-of-week ordering, which appears to be what your asking for. If alpha order really is what you want, then please state that in your question.

Comment: See edit... you read into my question a little much.  I am simply interested in ignoring the first row of header values and then sorting by either the alpha column or the integer column.  I'm also not familiar with TSQL using 'let' and '$'.  What should I lookup to find more information on the syntax you are using?

Comment: @cocogorilla Gotcha, see the updated answer. The only semi-tricky part as far as XQuery is concerned is that you have to reconstruct the table - it's not just a matter of sorting. I'm not a SQL guy, and I haven't tested that part of the answer, but I think this is pretty close to how you're supposed to execute a FLWOR in TSQL.